# Calling all 3k+ users!

Tags: discussion

So the Close Vote queue, while down somewhat since the last mod elections, is pretty full. I haven't reviewed in a while, and I see 342 to review, which means the number is probably that, if not higher.

Instead of asking how we can encourage people to go through the queue, I have a proposition (which can't go into an answer on the other question for reasons explained further on). I propose that we put together a few days/times when a group of at least five users can go through the queue and review. (If it's started soon before UTC 0:00 then 40 CVs can be reviewed in one session.)

Here's how I think we should put these together:

1. A user willing to head up a review session and remind those who pledged to help will write an answer to this question.
2. Users who can participate at the proposed time can comment and volunteer to participate.
3. When the time comes to review, the user who wrote the answer will remind users who commented to come help out.
4. The group will go through as many questions as it can, reviewing the CV queue.
5. Once the review session is over, then the answer is deleted, so as to free up clutter.

If you want, join this chatroom during review sessions to discuss anything that needs discussing. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators

If this can become a regular thing, at least for a week, we might be able to get the CV queue down to <100, which would be pretty impressive.

If you want to commit to a regular review time, say so in the answer. If a user wants to help at that time, but can't do it regularly, then they can comment and mention that, deleting the comment after the session has finished.

How does this sound?

Comment: Perhaps call another Mod election? This carved the queue down massively last time :). Seriously I like your plan and your energy...

Comment: I will just be around whenever possible and be sure to at least do 20 a day

Comment: The queue is not that long as it could. The main problem is that someone started to VTC old questions. I just skip them in reviews. Can mods ask to stop it?

Comment: I try to review the close queue every day.  I like your plan, but I think the root cause is the 20 limit per day.

Comment: @ElderGeek it may be, but I know that a lot of people hate to go through it (since it goes wayyy down during mod elections).

Comment: Every job has it's distasteful aspects. It still needs to be done. I don't mind, I occasionally find interesting questions to answer in the close queue.

Comment: @ElderGeek well that's why I brought up the idea of sort of "study groups" to review CVs. No one wants to do it, but misery loves company :p

Comment: I like the idea, I just never know what time I'll be able to squeeze in the time in advance. (Workng it now)

Comment: @ElderGeek well you can always commit to a date and back out. It's not like we ban you :p

Comment: Lol. Ok. I'm committing to now.

Comment: @ElderGeek hey! I'm doing some now!

Comment: And I just got the Qty:20 boot.

Comment: My schedule has been tough lately, but I made sure to get my 20 in this morning.  I'm showing 183 right now...good work everyone!

Comment: This actually seems to be working, only 135 in the queue today, I don't know if I have ever seen it so low :) I don't know what you did that others who brought this up did not but good job.

Comment: @MarkKirby I'm in General Chat and I annoy people there :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We did it!! A Hannukah/Chistmas Eve/Kwanzaa Eve Eve (:p) miracle! :D

[image]

Comment: Glad to be part of this historic moment.

Comment: It bounced back up on the 25th, but we're still working on it xD

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "HanaKwanMass to all!"  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well scheduled sessions didn't exactly happen, but that doesn't change the fact that ***we've reduced the queue by almost 300!***

It hasn't even been a month, and we're down to 53 (at the time of writing this answer) items to review!

[image]

We're not done yet, but look at how close it is to 0, especially compared to before.

Good job everyone! We're almost there!

Answer (score 2):

After going to 14, the CVs skyrocketed to 90+ :(.

Come one, everyone, let's try to clear it fully and keep it that way!

Just spend 5-10 minutes reviewing the queue at UTC 0:00, when the day resets. We'll get it down in no time.

Comment: If @Zanna stops VTC old questions, that will help a lot.